# How to add hibernate javadocs in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, javadoc

I am using Eclipse for the past two months. I didnt used javadocs in it before.
Today i searched for hibernate javadocs and got hibernate-3.2.2.ga-javadoc.jar.
But i dont know how to add it in eclipse. Any suggestions!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple steps to include hibernet in eclipse................

Visit 
    http://www.jboss.org/tools/download/stable/3_1_GA.html  (BROKEN LINK)

```
Downloaded file name should look like “HibernateTools-3.3.0.v200910281724M-H247-M4.zip”

Extract it with your favor zip tool

Copy the extracted plugin and feature folders to Eclipse’s plugin & feature folders

Restart Eclipse.......!!
It's Done.. :-)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also simply add the URL of the javadoc like http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/ **in the properties of the jar** !

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you right click on the JAR file under "Referenced Libraries" -> Properties -> Javadoc Location -> Javadoc in archive and then either point it to a jar you've imported into your workspace or on your local machine by using the "archive path" box.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete guide lines, that I have followed and it worked for me.

http://milindapro.blogspot.com/2011/10/add-hibernate-javadoc-to-eclipse.html

**Edit**

I am not promoteing myself. But I hope this will help to someone. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a link to download javadoc for hibernate 5.1?