# Eclipse: add javadoc

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, spring, javadoc

How can I generally add javadoc in eclipse for different packages.

As an example:
I want to add all the javadoc for hibernate in eclipse, but I don't know how.
I've read this article [How to add hibernate javadocs in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815619/how-to-add-hibernate-javadocs-in-eclipse) but I don't want to get hibernate tools because I already use STS and I don't understand the other comment.

I'm using eclipse on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another option is to use maven/m2eclipse to manage your dependencies.

It's way overkill if you have the problem for 1 or 2 libraries, but worth considering if you have a dozen.

Most open source projects publish both the jar and the -src.jar artifacts, and m2eclipse can go and download automatically the source for you.

Comment: Just right click the project and go to --> Maven --> Download Sources. Super easy!

Answer (score 26):

I am using Eclipse Helios x64 in Windows 7 x64.

In your project properties:

[image: Project Properties]

Comment: Thanks. It works, but I'll stick with maven. It's much faster to just get all sources and javadocs with only 1 click.

Comment: What about if it says "Non modifiable"? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19699157/how-to-get-google-api-client-android-javadocs-in-eclipse

Answer (score 3):

Run

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse -DdownloadJavadocs=true -DdownloadSources=true
```

and refresh your eclipse module. Voila! No need for any eclipse plugins (unless you are already using them).

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse *Kepler* (some years after the question, admittedly), there's a **Download JavaDoc** entry on the **Maven** submenu. This just downloaded the *Spring* JavaDoc (and the status message said "Downloading Javadoc and sources", but I haven't checked that).  (There's also a **Download Sources** entry on that submenu.)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the hibernate jar in the package explorer, then choose "Properties", and fill the "javadoc location" field.

[image]

Comment: In Indigo, there is one. But I'm pretty sure italso exists in previous versions. Check the screenshot in my edited answer.

Comment: I actually use Spring Tool Suite and Eclipse Helios and they both don't have those fields when I go at properties. I even went to hibernate3 like you. Maybe that's only in indigo, although it's weird since my STS is build over Indigo...

Answer (score 0):

Try viewing the properties of your project to add a JavaDoc Location.
[image]