# How can i add Spring API DOC to eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, spring

I'm trying to practice spring using Spring Tool Suite(Eclipse).

Everything is fine, except i want to see the api doc inside the IDE.

For example,

Application context = new ....
context.getBean() -> i want to see the explanation about this method directly from the eclipse.

but it says.

Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found

Any good idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870448/how-to-attach-source-or-javadoc-in-eclipse-for-any-jar-file-e-g-javafx. Hope this helps

Comment: THanks. solved with this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043489/eclipse-add-javadoc

Answer (score 1):

Go to the `build path`, where you have added `jars`. There select the `jar`, expand it and select `source attachment`. Now click on `edit` and add the **source attachment**.

Also you can use `build tools` like `maven`, which download source code automatically.