# How to obtain Play! framework's Javadocs?

Tags: java, eclipse, playframework, javadoc, playframework-2.3

I'm about to start a new project and we've decided to use Play!. I've configured my IDE (Eclipse Luna) but, unfortunately, there isn't any sign of the documentation  when I hover any function, class or so on.

Looking over the Internet I've came up with Play's github repo (https://github.com/playframework/playframework) and they've a documentation folder (https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/master/documentation).

So, how can I generate a Javadoc based on their Github documentation folder?

PS: I'm using the latest Play version, i.e. 2.3.6 where play command is replaced by activator.

Answer (score 7):

You have to pass the complete argument within quotation to the activator command.
Here is what worked for me:

```
.\activator "eclipse with-source=true"
```

I guess activator otherwhise recognizes `eclipse` and `with-source=true` as two seperate commands, rather than one command with an argument.

Answer (score 6):

The docs are not clear, which is why you and I got this annoying error.

1. cd into your web application folder
2. $ ./activator
3. [your project] $ eclipse with-source=true

Calling `./activator eclipse` works, but `./activator eclipse with-source=true` does not as it is (implied?) that it's running from within the activator shell.

Hope that helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem so I just used plugin for eclipse which is also useful for other libs:
http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-source-attacher

Comment: I've found that if you use Maven or Ivy, this problem disappears: automatically downloads sources and javadocs. Anyway, I turned from Play! into Vaadin, I felt more comfortable with it.

Answer (score 0):

Generate eclipse project with sources using sbt or activator: `eclipse with-source=true`. More details [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/IDE). Alternatively you can use [java decompiler](http://jd.benow.ca/) for eclipse - it might give you understanding of your libraries.

Comment: Not working... I created a a new application using "activator new yabe", changed directory to yabe, typed "activator eclipse with-sources=true" and the following message appears: [info] Successfully created Eclipse project files for project(s):
yabe Not a valid command: with-source Not a valid project ID: with-source Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[[next]]

Comment: [[continues]]Not a valid key: with-source (similar: watch-sources, watchSources, sources).. I tried this and worked intially: activator eclipse sources Loading project definition from ***\yabe\project Set current project to yabe (in build file:/***y/yabe/) About to create Eclipse project files for your project(s). Successfully created Eclipse project files for project(s): yabe[success]... But no Javadocs were created... What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

The Play server provides the docs for you at:

```
http://localhost:9000/@documentation/api/java/index.html
```

Unless you want offline documentation, on page https://www.playframework.com/documentation there are links to browse APIs for different versions, for example [Java 2.3x](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/java/index.html) or [Scala 2.3x](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html). The latest documentation version currently provided is [2.4.x](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/java/index.html)

Comment: Thank you, but I already knew the docu is there. What I really want is to set Javadocs into eclipse...

Comment: Eclipse is able to [fetch the docs via url](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8893722/989257), but if you want you can package the html files to a jar or zip and give that to Eclipse.

Comment: Um you are right. Anyway, it seems that the application must be running, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, the local server must be running if you use local url for the documentation to work. If you are online then the [play framework's urls are good](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/java/index.html)

Comment: I've set online dir but Javadocs are not showing: Note: An exception occurred while getting the Javadoc. See log for details.

Comment: Did you try to validate the javadoc url in Eclipse? Are you behind a proxy? Also try the local server url, if it works.

Comment: I validated the javadoc and seemed right. I'm at work but we haven't any proxy. Trying local...

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I decided to use an older version of Play! framework, as it comes with the "play" binary (not the activator one).

Placing myself onto my project, y typed:
`$ play`
`> eclipse with-source=true`

I don't know why, but I can't access similarly with:

`[1] $ activator`
  `> eclipse with-source=true`

because it gets stuck on [1] doesn't go on.